# How to reconstruct a Matrix A such given a basis of the null space

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Construct a 4 x 4 Matrix A such that {(1,2,3,4),(1,1,2,2)} is a basis of the N(A)

My confusion here lies in the fact that I need to build out a matrix given the basis of the null space.  How can I use the definition of the null space of (A) to help me reconstruct the Matrix? I just don't 'get it'

Comment: You can try to complete those two vector to a basis. After doing this, you easily can find a matrix whose kernel is the first two vector of the base ( i.e, in that  base, the matrix $$ \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0&0&0&0 \\ 0&0&1&0 \\ 0&0&0&1 \end{pmatrix}$$. Then just change the base again by conjugating with the base change matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take two vectors $v$ and $w$ such that $\{(1,2,3,4),(1,1,2,2),v,w\}$. For instance, you can take $v=(1,0,0,0)$ and $w=(0,1,0,0)$. Now consider the matrix$$M=\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1&0\\2&1&0&1\\3&2&0&0\\4&2&0&0\end{bmatrix},$$the columns of which are those four vectors. Finally, let$$B=\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}.$$Clearly, $\{(1,0,0,0),(0,1,0,0)\}$ is a basis of the null space of $B$. So, take\begin{align}A&=M.B.M^{-1}\\&=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & -1 & \frac12 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & -\frac12 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}.\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

The null space of a matrix is the orthogonal complement of its row space, so find a basis for the null space of $$\begin{bmatrix}1&2&3&4\\1&1&2&2\end{bmatrix},$$ which can be done with a one-step row-reduction. Take the resulting two vectors as two rows of $A$ and set the other two rows to be any linear combinations of these two vectors that you like. Two rows of zeros will do as well as anything else.