# How to create a Matrix A where the null space of A is the combination of two sets

Tags: linear-algebra

I just learned how to compute the null space of a matrix, but I can't figure out how to apply it to this advanced version...

Create a matrix A for which N(A) is all combinations of (2, 2, 1, 0) and
(3, 1, 0, 1).

I don't even know how to start it. Is [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3185518/how-to-reconstruct-a-matrix-a-such-given-a-basis-of-the-null-space) post the same question as mine?

Any help would be a huge stress relief to me.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi. Since the link you added actually addresses the same question as the one you have posted, I am not posting an answer, but if you are aware of the rank-nullity theorem and how to "extend a linearly independent set of vectors to a basis set of vectors", then you can do this. [those are two things for you to google in case you are not familiar with them]
The two vectors you have mentioned are linearly independent, you can extend them to a basis of $\mathbb{R}^4$ and get two more basis elements, and go use the rank-nullity theorem.

Comment: Okay, so that link I found IS the same problem as mine? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, it is the exact same problem, save with different numbers.

Comment: Thank you!  I'm going to try and work it then.

Comment: col 1 = 1 0 0 0
col 2 = 0 1 0 0
col 3 = -2 -2 0 0
col 4 = -3 -1 0 0
?

Comment: For this case, I believe you only need to determine a rectangular $2 \times 4$ matrix $A$ using the general approaches referred to above.  In particular, compute the null space of a new matrix based on the two vectors you already have - call this matrix $B$, where $B=\begin{bmatrix}2 & 2 & 1 & 0 \\ 3 & 1 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$.  You want to determine the null space of $B$.  The two vectors which are the solutions will be the two rows of $A$.  I hope this helps.